# Best way to back up home screen layout on Android?

Tags: backup, motorola-moto-g, launcher, home-screen, motorola

I have a Motorola Android phone in which I have around 400 apps that I have put into folders and carefully chosen a layout which has taken me a long time. I want a way to back up this layout and Motorola doesn't offer a this service (which other major phone manufacturers do). I know this can be done by using Nova Launcher and other launchers which have back up options but this means I have to recreate my layout again in Nova Launcher as it can't import my current layout from the Motorola Launcher which will take a long time.

Is there a way to at least dump all the current apps I own into Nova Launcher? Does anyone have any other ideas (other than getting a new phone)?

Comment: make some screenshots as backup

Answer (score 1):

Arrangement of apps whether on home screen or in app drawer is part of app data of launcher app. If your launcher app doesn't offer support for Import/Export of user settings, than try using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) to backup your launcher app's data. Verify the backup and see whether the user settings were indeed backed up not.

If adb solution is not useful than the only way is to get the device rooted and use a root based backup solution, such as by directly copying user settings from launcher app's data directory, or by using an app based backup solution such as Titanium Backup app.

**Note:** in all likelihood rooting the device would destroy all of your data.